# Prometheus - get delta between two last consecutive values

Tags: prometheus

I have a gauge metrics that, for instance, gives me a result like this when querying `panels_meters[30s]` gives me this result:

[image: query result]
and a query like this `delta(panels_meters[30s])` gives me the differenze between the last value and the value at 30 seconds ago.

BUT I want now the difference between the last two values, independently from the specified time. I just want something like `panels_meters[0] - panels_meters[1]` assuming panels_meters as an array of data sorted chronologically inverse.

Answer (score 11):

The `idelta` function is what you want.

Comment: Thank you brian-brazil! This seems exactly what I want!! Thanks a lot!